# Winapi Message box icon bitmap

Tags: winapi

I'm c++ programmer. I can make message box with my icon with .ico file extension. I can make with MSGBOXPARAMS. My question is, if got answers, to make MessageBox with my icon with .bmp file extension. Too make in MSGBOXPARAMS?

Comment: api accept only icon format and only from resource. even if you load bmp by self from file and create icon from it - no resource.. more easy create custom dialog via `DialogBox[Indirect]Param` in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with resource, create macro andn`BITMAP`value is of bitmap for MessageBoxIcon.

Sample:

head1.h

```
#define RCICON 23
```

res1.rc

```
#define RCICON 23
RCION BITMAP "example.bmp"
```

And try, MSGBOXPARAMS member for icon is example macro `RCICON`.